# Java - Adding multiple longs overflow/underflow check

Tags: java, overflow, underflow

Here I have 'e' which is an array of arrays.

`e[i].val()` returns a long value (positive or negative).

My goal is to add up all these values and return the mean value.

The problem is that the total could overflow or underflow causing incorrect calculation.

If the total does indeed reach `Long.MAX_VALUE` or `Long.MIN_VALUE` at the end of addition, then the total should remain at `Long.MAX_VALUE` or `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

The mean then being `Long.MAX_VALUE` or `Long.MIN_VALUE` / `e.length`.

Can only use basic Java, with the only possible exceptions Integer/Long.MIN/MAX_VALUE.

```
long total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < e.length; ++i) {
    total = e[i].val();
}
mean = total/e.length.
```

Comment: Can you use methods like [`Math.addExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#addExact(long,long)) (Java 8+)?

Comment: Cannot use Math.-something